# Spring boot post data to url implementation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm new in springboot i wanna ask how to implements send data to specified url if the parameter like this

```
http://api.gosmsgateway.net/masking/api/Send.php?username=ecgo&mobile=082111937220&message=7521&password=123456
```

Comment: What you are doing is querystring parameter, and that is GET method! Check the link in https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/ and it has got an example of how to POST service and invoke it

Comment: this is previous code to send sms but i already change to local sms provider and code li this '@Component
public class TencentSmsOperator implements SmsOperator {
    @Value("${sms.appid:1400051631}")
    private int appid;
    @Value("${sms.appkey:ccdb1747af0916ae49f3beebedb1efd2}")
    private String appkey;
    @Value("${sms.templId:59810}")
    private int templId;
    @Value("${sms.sign:小鸣单车}")
    private String sign;
    @Value("${sms.nationCode:86}")
    private String nationCode;

Comment: i just want to change class using local sms provider not from tencent cloud

Answer (score 1):

I think you are wrong because this url looks like GET method but if you want, I will show you how to sent POST request.

In Spring you can use [Rest Template](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html) for making request.

[Here is](https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-rest/) also officially example how to use it provide by Spring.

So in your case you have to send the request to url `http://api.gosmsgateway.net/masking/api/Send.php` with that params:
`username=ecgo&mobile=082111937220&message=7521&password=123456` 
based on for example [this method.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html#postForLocation-java.lang.String-java.lang.Object-java.lang.Object...-)

```
String url = "http://api.gosmsgateway.net/masking/api/Send.php";
Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>(); // put here your params.

RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
template.postForLocation(url, postObject, params);
```

But I think you shouldn't send your params in url because this is really bad practice.

Comment: it's not a question of bad practice, but what the API that is called requires. And here it's query parameters. And you can of course use request parameters in POST requests.